# Сумма элементов подмассива в массиве

Tags: javascript

```js
function getDivisorsRange(a, b) {
  if (a > b) {
    var temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
  }
  result = new Array();
  var index = 0;
  for (let i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    result.push({
      num: i,
      divisors: new Array(),
    })
    var sum = 0;
    for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      if (i % j == 0) {
        result[index].divisors.push(j);
        sum += result;
      }
    }
    index++;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(getDivisorsRange(100, 300));
```

Есть массив с числами в заданном диапазоне, в нем еще массивы, каждый из которых это делители для данного числа. Но мне нужны не сами делители, а их сумма в массиве, чтобы я мог к ней обратиться.То бишь если число 100, то его сумма делителей 217

Comment: `sum += j` а не `sum += result`

Comment: а выводить тогда .push(sum)? при таком выводе какие то странные цифры выходят

Comment: Лучше воспользоваться `reduce`.